# How to list the source table name and columns and extended properties ( description ) of a View

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-view, set-returning-functions

I try to find

- source table names
- columns (and another properties )
- extended properties ( description )
  of a View

and finally I use this way

0- because of fields alias in a view , I tried to find real name of a column . so I used this function

```
          Create FUNCTION [dbo].[_D_RealColumnName]
       (@ViewName NVarChar(50),@ColumnName NVarChar(50))RETURNS NVarChar(50)
       AS BEGIN
       DECLARE @R NVarchar(50)
        Set @R=(SELECT name 
                 FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set 
                (N'SELECT *   from  '+@ViewName, null, 1) 
                Where source_column=@ColumnName)
        RETURN IsNUll(@R ,@ColumnName )
       END
```

1- create a view for collect information named "[_I_AllFields]"

```
        CREATE View [dbo].[_I_AllFields] as 
    SELECT        *
    FROM            (SELECT        T .TABLE_NAME AS TName, C.COLUMN_NAME AS FName, C.ORDINAL_POSITION AS FSeq, D .value AS FDesc, C.DATA_TYPE AS FType, C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS FLen, F.collation_name AS Coll, 
                                                F.is_identity AS IsIdentity, F.is_nullable AS IsNullAble, CONVERT(NVarChar(50), '') VName
                      FROM            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T INNER JOIN
                                                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C ON C.TABLE_NAME = T .TABLE_NAME INNER JOIN
                                                sys.columns AS F ON F.object_id = OBJECT_ID(T .TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T .TABLE_NAME) AND F.name = C.COLUMN_NAME LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                sys.extended_properties AS D ON D .major_id = F.object_id AND D .minor_id = F.column_id AND D .Name = 'MS_Description') TList
    UNION
    SELECT        VCU.TABLE_NAME TName, [dbo].[_D_RealColumnName](VCU.VIEW_NAME, VCU.COLUMN_NAME) FName, TAF.FSeq, TAF.FDesc, TAF.FType, TAF.FLen, TAF.Coll, IsIdentity, IsNullAble, VCU.VIEW_NAME VName
    FROM            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE AS VCU INNER JOIN
                         (SELECT        T .TABLE_NAME AS TName, C.COLUMN_NAME AS FName, C.ORDINAL_POSITION AS FSeq, D .value AS FDesc, C.DATA_TYPE AS FType, C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS FLen, F.collation_name AS Coll, 
                                                     F.is_identity AS IsIdentity, F.is_nullable AS IsNullAble
                           FROM            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T INNER JOIN
                                                     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C ON C.TABLE_NAME = T .TABLE_NAME INNER JOIN
                                                     sys.columns AS F ON F.object_id = OBJECT_ID(T .TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T .TABLE_NAME) AND F.name = C.COLUMN_NAME LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                     sys.extended_properties AS D ON D .major_id = F.object_id AND D .minor_id = F.column_id AND D .Name = 'MS_Description') TAF ON VCU.TABLE_NAME = TAF.TName AND VCU.COLUMN_NAME = TAF.FName
```

2- Create a function to get information named "_D_Field"

```
CREATE 
FUNCTION [dbo].[_D_Field](
@InTName VarChar(100)

) RETURNS @Ans Table (
         TName VarChar(70)
        ,FName VarChar(70)
      ,FSeq int
      ,FDesc NVarChar(70)
            ,FType NVarChar(10)
            ,FLen  int
            )
AS BEGIN   
      If Not Object_ID(@InTName,'U') Is Null
                        Insert into @Ans 
                        SELECT Convert(VarChar(70),TName)TName ,
                        Convert(VarChar(70),FName)FName ,Convert(Int,FSeq)FSeq ,
                        Case When IsNull(FDesc,'')='' Then Convert(VarChar(70),FName) 
                        Else Case When Substring(Convert(VarChar(70),FDesc),1,1)='*' Then Case When Substring(Convert(VarChar(70),FDesc),2,1)='' Then Convert(VarChar(70),FName) 
                                                                                                                                                            Else Substring(Convert(VarChar(70),FDesc),2,70)End
                        Else Convert(VarChar(70),FDesc) End End FDesc,

                        FType,IsNull(FLen,0)FLen
                        FROM _I_AllFields
                        where TName=@InTName
     Else
                        Insert into @Ans 
                        SELECT Convert(VarChar(70),TName)TName ,Convert(VarChar(70),FName)FName ,Convert(Int,FSeq)FSeq ,
                        Case When IsNull(FDesc,'')='' Then Convert(VarChar(70),FName) 
                        Else Case When Substring(Convert(VarChar(70),FDesc),1,1)='*' Then Case When Substring(Convert(VarChar(70),FDesc),2,1)='' Then Convert(VarChar(70),FName) 
                                                                                                                                                            Else Substring(Convert(VarChar(70),FDesc),2,70)End
                        Else Convert(VarChar(70),FDesc) End End FDesc,

                        FType,IsNull(FLen,0)FLen
                        FROM _I_AllFields
                        where VName=@InTName
            
RETURN 
END
```

3- finally I used this commands

```
Select * From dbo._D_Field('my_View_Name')
```

or

```
Select * From dbo._D_Field('my_Table_Name')
```

is it correct or I can find simple way?

Comment: I change the view , because of another description

Comment: Another change to using real field name
[dbo].[_D_RealColumnName](VCU.VIEW_NAME, VCU.COLUMN_NAME) FName